# How to get the count of occurrence from comma separated string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following two tables in `Oracle 8i`

For each col1 in T1 table, we need to find out the number of occurrences in T2 table (for matching col3).

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to achieve this in Oracle using a single query (without creating temporary table)?

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddf2e)

**EXPECTED RESULT**

‘C1’ -- 10 -- 1

‘C1’ -- 8 -- 1

‘C2’ -- 10 -- 1

‘C3’ -- 10 -- 0

‘C4’ -- 10 -- 2

**SQL**

```
--Table 1
CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 varchar2(2), col2 varchar(8), col3 NUMBER);

INSERT INTO T1  (col1, col2, col3) VALUES  ('C1', 'john',10);
INSERT INTO T1  (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('C1', 'nishal',8);
INSERT INTO T1  (col1, col2, col3) VALUES  ('C2', 'piers',10);
INSERT INTO T1  (col1, col2, col3) VALUES  ('C3', 'sara',10);
INSERT INTO T1  (col1, col2, col3) VALUES  ('C4', 'lijo',10);


--Table 2

CREATE TABLE T2 (col1 varchar2(2), col2 varchar(8), col3 NUMBER);

INSERT INTO T2  (col1, col2 , col3) VALUES ('R0', 'C1,C4',10);
INSERT INTO T2  (col1, col2 , col3) VALUES ('R1', 'C1',8);
INSERT INTO T2  (col1, col2 , col3) VALUES ('R2', 'C2,C4',10);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddf2e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  T1.col1
,       T1.col3
,       count(T2.col1)
from    T1
left join
        T2
on      T1.col3 = T2.col3
        and ',' || T2.col2 || ',' like '%,' || T1.col1 || ',%'
group by
        T1.col1
,       T1.col3
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddf2e/3/0)

Comment: just curious why enclose the columns in joining condition with commas? Can't it simply be done with `and  T2.col2  like '%' || T1.col1 || '%'`?

Comment: @dipendu: to avoid `C1` matching `C11,C12`